# Adjust Function by Other Values' Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

[image: Screenshot]

Trying to display the value of `wl3` in the top right box, value should change while manipulating values of `wl1` and `wl2` in the two boxes to its left, how do I do it? Code for reference

```
wl3[wl1_, wl2_] := wl1 + wl2;
θrefr[θinc_, n1_, n2_] := θinc*n1/n2;
Manipulate[
 Grid[
  {{Label,
    {Manipulate[wl1, {wl1, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      FrameLabel -> "Wavelength1"]},
    {Manipulate[wl2, {wl2, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      FrameLabel -> "Wavelength2"]},
    {wl3[wl1, wl2]}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Trying to display the value of wl3 in the top right box

I would not use Manipulate inside Manipulate. You can do all this with one manipulate.

[image]

The idea is to use `None` for Manipulate, and then use `Grid` to layout both the control variables and also the output which normally goes where `None` now sits. But to do this, you need to use `Dynamic` for the output part.

```
wl3[wl1_, wl2_] := wl1 + wl2;
Manipulate[
 None,
 Grid[{
   (*first two grids are control variables *)
   {Grid[{{"Wavelength1", 
       Manipulator[Dynamic[wl1, {wl1 = #} &], {0, 1, .1}, 
        ImageSize -> Tiny]}, {Dynamic[wl1]}}, Frame -> True],

    Grid[{{"Wavelength2", 
       Manipulator[Dynamic[wl2, {wl2 = #} &], {0, 1, .1}, 
        ImageSize -> Tiny]}, {Dynamic[wl2]}}, Frame -> True],

    (*this is the output, must be dynamic *)
    Grid[{{"wl1+wl2"},
      {Dynamic@Row[{ wl1,"+",wl2," = ",wl3[wl1,wl2]}]}},Frame->True]

    }}, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Background -> White
  ],

 Alignment -> Center, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 1, 
 ContentSize -> {0}, SynchronousInitialization -> True, 
 ContinuousAction -> True, Alignment -> Center, Paneled -> True, 
 Frame -> False
 ]
```